# Code coverage at for loop does not cover code inside loop

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

Why is my apex test not getting the material inside the for loop? I have test data, and the method gets called. I just don't have coverage for anything inside the for loops as seen below. I included only the method that I am trying to achieve coverage for. The inner wrapper it uses is covered.

```
@testVisible public Map<Decimal,Tab> getAllOptions {
      get {
              
              Map<String,OptionGroup> optionGroupsByOptionCode = new Map<String,OptionGroup>();
              Map<String,Options__c[]> OptionsByUDC = new Map<String,Options__c[]>();
              Map<String,String> OptionsByAUDC = new Map<String,String>();
              Map<String,String> ValueByAUDC = new Map<String,String>();
              
              List<Options__c> optOnOrder = [SELECT UDC__c, UDC_Desc__c, Value_Desc__c FROM Options__c WHERE SPOrder__c = :this.orderId];
              
              for(Options__c o :optOnOrder) {
                  String UDCLower = o.UDC__c.toLowerCase();
                  if (!OptionsByUDC.containsKey(UDCLower)) {
                      OptionsByAUDC.put(o.UDC__c,o.UDC_Desc__c);
                      OptionsByUDC.put(UDCLower,new List<Options__c>());
                      ValueByAUDC.put(o.UDC__c, o.Value_Desc__c);
                  }
                  OptionsByUDC.get(UDCLower).add(o);
              }

              Set<Decimal> groupSeqSet = new Set<Decimal>();
              
              Map<Decimal,String> tabMap = new Map<Decimal,String>();
              
              Map<Decimal,Tab> tabs = new Map<Decimal,Tab>();
              
              List<Option_Group__c> seqPull = [SELECT Option_Group_Seq__c FROM Option_Group__c Where Option_Priority_Level__c <=3];
              
              for (Option_Group__c og: seqPull){
                  groupSeqSet.add(og.Option_Group_Seq__c);   
              }
              
              for(Decimal tabSeq: groupSeqSet){
                  Tab tab = new Tab();
                  String tabName='';
                  
                  List<Option_Group__c> groupPull = [SELECT Option_Group__c, Option_Code__c, Option_Seq__c FROM Option_Group__c Where Option_Group_Seq__c = :tabSeq and Option_Priority_Level__c <=3];
                  
                  Map<Id, Option_Group__c> objGmap = new Map<Id, Option_Group__c>(groupPull);
                  Set<Id> objIDs = new Set<Id>();
                  
                  for (Option_Group__c og2: groupPull){
                      objIDs.add(og2.Id);
                      tabName = og2.Option_Group__c;
                  }
                  Map<Decimal,Option> options = new Map<Decimal,Option>();
                  for(Option_Group__c og3: groupPull){
                      if(OptionsByAUDC.containsKey(og3.Option_Code__c)) {
                          Option option= new Option();
                          option.udcdesc=ValueByAUDC.get(og3.Option_Code__c);
                          option.optdesc=OptionsByAUDC.get(og3.Option_Code__c);
                          
                          options.put(og3.Option_Seq__c,option);
                      //    System.debug('tabseq:'+tabseq+' option:'+og3);
                      }
                  }
                  tab.tabName=tabName;
                  tab.options=options;
                  
                  
                  if(!tab.options.isEmpty()) {
                      tabs.put(tabSeq,tab);
                  }
              }      
              getAllOptions = tabs;
          return getAllOptions;
      } private set;
```

Apex test class

```
@isTest public class SP2OptionsControllerTest {
    
    public static testMethod void testMyController(){
        
        SPOrders__c stu = new SPOrders__c();
        stu.Name='order';
        stu.Order_ID__c='order1';
        insert stu;
        
        SPOrders__c c = [select id,name from SPOrders__c WHERE Name = 'order' limit 1];
        
        Options__c opt = new Options__c();
        opt.UDC__c = 'TST';
        opt.UDC_Desc__c = 'TestDesc';
        opt.SPOrder__c = c.Id;
        opt.Value_Desc__c='TestValue';
        insert opt;
        
        Options__c opt2 = new Options__c();
        opt.UDC__c = 'TST2';
        opt.UDC_Desc__c = 'TestDesc';
        opt.SPOrder__c = c.Id;
        opt.Value_Desc__c='TestValue';
        insert opt2;
        
        Option_Group__c optGroup = new Option_Group__c();
        optGroup.Option_Code__c = 'TST';
        optGroup.Option_Group__c = 'TSTGROUP';
        optGroup.Option_Group_Seq__c = 1;
        optGroup.Option_Seq__c = 1;
        insert optGroup;
        
        Option_Group__c optGroup2 = new Option_Group__c();
        optGroup.Option_Code__c = 'TST2';
        optGroup.Option_Group__c = 'TSTGROUP';
        optGroup.Option_Group_Seq__c = 1;
        optGroup.Option_Seq__c = 2;
        insert optGroup2;
        
        Options__c oc = [select id,UDC_Desc__c, Value_Desc__c,UDC__c from Options__c WHERE UDC_Desc__c = 'TestDesc'];

        Option_Group__c optG = [SELECT Option_Code__c, Option_Group__c, Option_Group_Seq__c, Option_Seq__c from Option_Group__c WHERE Option_Group__c = 'TSTGROUP'];
        
        
        PageReference pageRef = Page.SP2Options;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', c.id);
        
        SP2OptionsController con = new SP2OptionsController();
        
        if(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id') == null){
            con.orderId = c.id;
        }
        
        SP2OptionsController.Option conOption = new SP2OptionsController.Option();
        conOption.optdesc = oc.Value_Desc__c;
        conOption.udcdesc = oc.UDC_Desc__c;
              
        SP2OptionsController.Tab t = new SP2OptionsController.Tab();
        t.tabname = optG.Option_Group__c;
        t.options = new Map<Decimal, SP2OptionsController.Option>();
        t.options.put(1,conOption);
        String tabname ='';
        
        SP2OptionsController.OptionGroup conOptionGroup = new SP2OptionsController.OptionGroup();
        conOptionGroup.og = optG;
        conOptionGroup.Options = [select id,UDC_Desc__c, Value_Desc__c from Options__c WHERE UDC_Desc__c = 'TestDesc'];
        conOptionGroup.withOptionGroup(conOptionGroup.og);
        conOptionGroup.withOptions(conOptionGroup.Options);      

        con.getAllOptions = new Map<Decimal, SP2OptionsController.Tab>();
        con.getAllOptions.put(1, t);
        con.getAllOptions.put(2, t);

    }
}
```

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re setting `seqPull` equal to the results of a selective query, based on a priority level value of <= 3. Your test records don’t have a priority value defined, so your query returns a list of 0 records, so there’s nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. You were correct. Setting priority level on my mock data worked.